# Error link admin when install Magento 2.1 sample finish!

Tags: error, installation, link

When finish install **Magento sample 2.1**, i visit the following link admin:

```
http://magento21_sample.m:8012/admin/
```

then redirect link:

```
http://magento21_sample.m:8012/admin/http:/index/magento21_sample.m:8012/admin/admin/index/index/key/a9afc5f3ca6ea7547fe61e05d3b43258c6e5c34ab485986aebbe1a388e44c97a/
```

and not connect.

After, i run link: `http://magento21_sample.m:8012/`
I see a lot of error not found in console:

```
GET http://magento21_sample.m:8012/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/vi_VN/mage/calendar.css 404 (Not Found)
(index):22 GET http://magento21_sample.m:8012/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/vi_VN/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 
(index):21 GET http://magento21_sample.m:8012/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/vi_VN/requirejs/require.js 
(index):126 GET http://magento21_sample.m:8012/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/vi_VN/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):22 GET http://magento21_sample.m:8012/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/vi_VN/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

1) Clear Var directory.

2) Delete content of \pub\static keep .htaccess file.

3) Edit \app\etc\di.xml as follows.

Nearly line no 606 Replace

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>`

With

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>`

4) Refresh your url.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Error link of the admin beacause domain has special character "_". can fix by using a different domain.